# How can I plot image data in Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, plot

I would like to plot some image binary data on a grayscale matrix-like graph with custom values on axes. I'm using Perl on a Windows machine but I can't fine the right module to do this. I'm already using GD::Graph to plot other type of data but it seems unsuitable for this specific task.

Comment: @Space: yep, you got it.

Comment: It would help if we know what your requirements were and why GD::Graph doesn't meet them. As I recall, I've not had a problem doing this with GD::Graph. What have you tried so far?

Comment: gnuplot is very flexible. I had to plot matrix data as a gray scale image and this seemed quite out of the GD::Graph capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) very useful for such tasks. There are Perl modules also available for this. i.e. [Chart::Gnuplot](http://search.cpan.org/~kwmak/Chart-Gnuplot-0.14/lib/Chart/Gnuplot.pm)

Comment: With ActivePerl 5.10 on Windows? I can't find the package on ActiveState repositories.

Comment: @angaran : You'll have to add some repositories in that case. Go to `Edit`->`Preferences`. There are a number of suggested repositories you can add from the 'Suggested:' drop-down list.

Comment: @angaran : You may be viewing packages currently installed in that case. You need to view all packages by selecting the appropriate button or hitting `Ctrl+1`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zaid: damn! I clicked the icon by mistake! My fault! I'll try that package and let you know if i'm satisfied.